# Delete duplicate text in Atribute table, qgis

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression

I'm trying to label correctly a set of points in my map. They refer to localities and water analyses for those places in Spain. But the information in one of the fields is duplicated, it's written two times. I'm using QGIS 2.18

[image: point with wrong text]

I'm trying to delete the duplicate text from a field in my Attribute table, but so far, I've not been able to find the right expression. The Field is called Municipio.
I've tried with the expression:
replace ( "Municipio", 'Municipio', ' ' ) 
but it's not working.

Any idea ?

[image: Points with problems from Attribute table]

Answer (score 2):

To retain only the first part of a duplicated `Municipio` field, try an expression below in the Field Calculator.

```
CASE WHEN left("Municipio", strpos("Municipio", '\\s')-1) 
          IS 
          left(replace("Municipio", left("Municipio", strpos("Municipio", '\\s')), ''), 
               strpos("Municipio", '\\s')-1)
THEN left("Municipio", strpos("Municipio", '\\s')-1)
ELSE "Municipio"
END
```

Caveats:

- Not sure how you would like to handle it if we have triple words... this expression only keeps the first.
- This does not work well with a Municipio which includes space in its name.

[image]

Comment: [@Kazuhito](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84455/kazuhito) I just want miserably to extend your answer. I suppose [@prigual](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/53511/prigual) needs encoding adjustment, e.g. UTF-8, which may show letters instead of the question marks.

Comment: @Kazuhito. Yes, the expression from Kazuhito it's working. I only need to keep the first name.  I don't understand the expression but it works fine.( I'll study the pexression later :). And yes, I still have a problem with the font, like the question marks, but I may ask another question for that. It's more clear for the forum, thanks both of you